# Synchronizing code for multiple users

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, network-share, file-sharing, synchronization

I'm a beginner in all this and am working on a project with a few other people.
I'm facing some problems.

- My code is to worked on by another person simultaneously.
- I want to perform staging on a server.

How do  I maintain my code like that?

And what all problems can occur by doing all this? Like overwrite problems, loss of data...My boss wants me to list 10.

Can someone help?

Comment: Have you looked at *any* version control software? Git, SVN, etc...

Comment: Your boss wants you to list 10 disadvantages or issues? Are you sure you didn't mean your *professor* wants you to list 10 for your *homework*?

Comment: You need 10?  This is ridiculous.  This is IT, not a slate carried down the mountain after listening to God.  One reason is all a person needs to make a decision about avoiding serious problems in IT.  If that really is coming from your boss, I'd look for another job.  The answer on revision control software is a good one.

Comment: Server Fault is not your personal research service. Please spend some time researching [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) and [version control software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software) on your own. If you then have specific questions on the *system administration aspects* related to a particular package you may ask those questions here and we will try to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by a VCS (Version control system). There are many different out there. Please evaluate yourself.

Examples:

- Subversion
- Mercurial
- Git

to name only a few.

The main difference between different systems are that some a central while other are decentral.

Comment: Thanks! The answer helped a lot!
And sorry for posting an off-topic question. Apologies to you all.

And yes, "boss". I'm an intern.